# Visual Studio Debug says Unable to launch IIS Express Web server (failed to register localhost:443)

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012, .NET 4.5. I just downloaded NuGetGalary from github and trying to build and run the Web application of it.

I am using IIS Express with project Url `http://localhost:8081`

But when I launch the project, I get the following error message

[image: Error message]

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Silly reason,

I used [this Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973094/en-us) to find out what was wrong. Turned out it was VMWare Workstation Server service holding up the 443 port. I stopped the service and now project launches fine.

Comment: For me it was Skype.  I went into Skype settings, unchecked the box to use ports 80 and 443, and restarted it.  Then the server launched.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't add comments yet, I put my thoughts here.

Since you launch the site on "localhost:8081", and it can't be launched because of port 443 being used, it's probably that inside the solution, some service is started, and by default is running on 443.

Your solution consisted of stopping the app "VMWare Workstation Server" which seemed to be using the same port. This might not always be possible, depending the type of app using the port.

What you could also have done (maybe), is configuring the project/service (inside Visual Studio) to use another port than 443.

You can usually find this element in the project properties.

Comment: I did change the port to 8081, but somehow it needed to bind on 443 (may be for ssl part of the puzzle). I couldn't find anything on Project properties dialog where I can change the 2nd port.